# How to stop code execution of for loop from try/except in a Pythonic way?

Tags: python, loops, structure, break, try-except

I've got some Python code as follows:

```
for emailCredentials in emailCredentialsList:
   try:
       if not emailCredentials.valid:
           emailCredentials.refresh()
   except EmailCredentialRefreshError as e:
       emailCredentials.active = False
       emailCredentials.save()
       # HERE I WANT TO STOP THIS ITERATION OF THE FOR LOOP 
       # SO THAT THE CODE BELOW THIS DOESN'T RUN ANYMORE. BUT HOW?

   # a lot more code here that scrapes the email box for interesting information
```

And as I already commented in the code, if the `EmailCredentialRefreshError` is thrown I want this iteration of the for loop to stop and move to the next item in the `emailCredentialsList`. I can't use a `break` because that would stop the whole loop and it wouldn't cover the other items in the loop. I can of course wrap all the code in the try/except, but I would like to keep them close together so that the code remains readable.

What is the most Pythonic way of solving this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the `continue` statement. This continues to the next iteration of the loop.

```
for emailCredentials in emailCredentialsList:
   try:
       if not emailCredentials.valid:
           emailCredentials.refresh()
   except EmailCredentialRefreshError as e:
       emailCredentials.active = False
       emailCredentials.save()
       continue
   <more code>
```

Comment: this will work, of course; but do you have a citation (e.g., PEP) that this is the Pythonic way to do it?

Comment: @mfrankli well the only other way would be to move the whole rest of the loop body into the `try`'s `else` block, and [*"flat is better than nested"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), not to mention that (as the OP points out) this makes it harder to understand the control flow as the `continue` is a long way from the `for`.

Comment: `break` and `continue` are valid statements and it would be pythonic. But as @jonrsharpe mentioned, you can call `raise` in exception and handle the *unexceptional part* in the else block too. It is all about flavour and taste

Comment: @jonrsharpe, "Flat is better than nested" is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for; since the question explicitly asks for "most Pythonic", it seemed important to cite something like that.